# What's this coin?

Tags: identification, numismatics

[image][image]

Can anyone tell me what this coin is?

Comment: What do you know about the coin? Where did you find it? When? What did the previous owner tell you?

Comment: A transcription of the text should help answerers and the visually impaired.

Comment: The reverse looks a lot like this Syrian tetradracma. https://www.numisbids.com/n.php?p=lot&sid=2501&lot=17

Comment: @Alex Sure looks very much alike, but mind making that an answer? Also, the blurring of the inscriptions hints that this might be a molded copy.

Comment: In addition to the other questions of SJuan76: What are Diameter and weight?

Comment: Also worth noting, of course, that if it is meant to be a Tetradrachm of King Antiochus VII then it should be minted in silver.